# Use a prompt in an wxpython textctrl field

Tags: wxpython, user-input

I'd like to put a prompt (italic, grey, unchangeable text) into an input field, which is removed when the user types the first character (or the field is focussed, which would not be as nice).

The rationale is to give the user some hint about the meaning of the field as long as it's empty.

Documentation at 
https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html
says that text styles are (only?) available for multi-line fields, which I do not need.

Can this be achieved with the wxpython TextCtrl? How?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to set the `Font` to have the attributes that you require and then reset them when the "Hint" text is backspaced.
i.e.

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Test TextCtrl')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,value="Normal Text",pos=(10,10),size=(350,30))
        self.text2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,value="Italic greyed hint text",pos=(10,40),size=(350,30))
        font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.text2.SetFont(font)
        self.text2.SetForegroundColour('#848484')
        self.text2.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.On_Text_Active)
        self.Show()

    def On_Text_Active(self, event):
        if self.text2.GetForegroundColour() == '#848484':
            font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
            self.text2.SetFont(font)
            self.text2.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
            self.text2.SetValue('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]